Issue with custom tab bar
I'm having an issue with a custom tab bar in SwiftUI. It works fine if you go through the views using the tab bar, but I'm having a weird issue. In searchview() I have a button to open a navigation stack using a full screen cover. Once I dismiss the views from full screen cover, a toolbar is appearing on top of my custom tab bar, moving the views around 20 px on top of the tab bar. Any ideas how to solve this?
import SwiftUI

struct NewTabView: View {
    let user: User
    @StateObject private var programsViewModel = ProgramViewModel()
    @StateObject private var workoutsViewModel = WorkoutViewModel()

    @State var currentTab: HomeTab = .home
    @State private var isShowingFullScreenCover = false
    
    init(user: User) {
        self.user = user
        UITabBar.appearance().isHidden = true
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            TabView(selection: $currentTab) {
                MainView(workoutsViewModel: workoutsViewModel, user: user)
                    .applyBG()
                    .tag(HomeTab.home)
                
                SearchView()
                    .applyBG()
                    .tag(HomeTab.workouts)
                
                ProgramLoaderView(user: user, programsViewModel: programsViewModel)
                    .applyBG()
                    .tag(HomeTab.program)
                
                LikedView()
                    .applyBG()
                    .tag(HomeTab.liked)
                
                ActivityView()
                    .applyBG()
                    .tag(HomeTab.you)
            }
            
            CustomTab(currentTab: $currentTab)
                .background(.black.opacity(0.9))
        }
    }
}

struct CustomTab: View {
    @Binding var currentTab: HomeTab
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                ForEach(HomeTab.allCases, id: \.rawValue) { tab in
                    Button {
                        withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.2)) {
                            currentTab = tab
                        }
                    } label: {
                        VStack {
                            Image(systemName: tab.symbol)
                                .renderingMode(.template)
                                .resizable()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                                .foregroundStyle(currentTab == tab ? .white : .gray)
                         
                            Circle()
                                .fill(.red.opacity(0.8))
                                .frame(width: 10, height: 10)
                                .opacity(currentTab == tab ? 1 : 0)
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        }
        .frame(height: 30)
        .padding(.bottom, 10)
        .padding([.top])
    }
}

extension View {
    func applyBG() -> some View {
        self
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}



Try removing UITabBar.appearance().isHidden = true, then apply .toolbarBackground(.hidden, for: .tabBar) to each of the separate views inside the TabView. If that doesn't fix it, please show how SearchView is implemented.
